# Check External Storage function not working

Tags: android

I am trying to check if Sd card is available or not after I have created a sd card  and then mounted to emulator.and gave required permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then created a function named chekSd that  returns a boolean value .The  button is suppose to be disable once the sdcard unmounted .But its not.What am i doing wrong here

```
boolean isSdavailableAndWriable=chekSd();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveEx);
    save.setEnabled(isSdavailableAndWriable);
}


private boolean chekSd() {

    if( Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        if( !(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: please define "sdcard". If you mean a physical SD card, this code won't work

Comment: Android's `ExternalStorage` is not guaranteed to be always referring to the external sdcard. It is entirely up to device manufacturer to set a specific storage as default and android's `ExternalStorage` will point to that path. To see all mounted media you can run `mount` command and analyze th output.

Comment: @S.D. actually I think that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` will always point to the built-in memory, I haven't met any device were that method would point to a physical sd

Comment: Well i have such devices. Version 2 where /sdcard is indeed the micro SD card.

Answer (score 0):

Add both the permission to handle external SD card status

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you want to get the secondary storage like external SD card than use

```
String secondaryStoragePath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
        if (secondaryStoragePath != null) 
             return true;
        else
            return false;
```

Comment: Check the edited answer If you want to get the secondary storage like external SD card than use